# how to export to pdf with syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, pdf-generation, syntax-highlighting

I need an extension in intellij or vscode or some app to transform my codes into pdf.

I tried to use the app notion but it doesn't export with syntax highlighting.

*Edit:
I know it seems to have a very easy answer, but I was thinking exclusively about Intellij Community. I have to export my code into a legible PDF with syntax highlights without having to leave the IDEA. The current way to achieve exactly what I want is to copy the code in Intellij, paste it into Visual Studio Code (to get the syntax right), copy it again and paste it into Google Docs to change the background color (since I prefer to code in darker colors and want this in the PDF as well), and then save as a PDF.

This is a lot of steps for a simple task. The closest I can get is using Notion, where I can paste and copy the code into a Notion file (in the code area using markdown), and then simply save the file as a PDF. However, the syntax highlighting is ignored when exported to PDF.

Comment: convert your code to an HTML page with a `pre` tag and add a JavaScript based syntax highlighter, convert (print) this page with a browser to pdf

Comment: What are some recommended syntax highlighters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have settings for printing PDFs directly, but you can try the following solutions:

- Use `File | Export | File or Selection to HTML` to export code to an HTML file. Open this file in a browser, and use the print feature in the browser to print a pdf.
- Install software that emulates printer in your system and creates PDF as output and run `File | Print` action from the IDE.

Comment: Well, it works. Its not very functional when you have a lot of files and it's not exactly what i was looking for, but i think that what i want doesn't really exists, but yeah, thank you!

Comment: I don't see File > Export on 1.85.0-insider on cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20231130.

Answer (score 10):

**1. Install extension with name **`Print`****

Extension Id : **`pdconsec.vscode-print`**

[Visual Studio Extension Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print)

**2. Create HTML in Browser**

View -> Command Pallete -> Print

**3. Print as PDF from Browser**

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a VSCode extension that allows you to export source code as HTML with syntax highlighting.
This extension also has the ability to export PDFs and images, so if you are interested, please see the following pages.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Aniny.codetohtml
https://github.com/Aniny21/CodeToHTML